# Транзакция в Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: postgresql, spring

Добрый день. Нужно вставить данные сразу в 2 таблицы. На сколько я понимаю это надо делать в транзакционном блоке. Подскажите как правильно это делать в jsbcTemplate. БД - postgre.
Мои дао методы пока что выглядят таким образом:

```
 @Override
public int createUser(User user) {
    return jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_CREATE_USER, user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(),true,user.getRegistrationDate(), user.getPassword(), user.getEmail());
}

@Override
public int addRole(User user, Role role) {
    return jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_ADD_ROLE, user.getId(), role.getId());
}
```

Сервис добавления полноценного юзера (с ролями) в бд

```
@Override
public void createUser(User user) {
        userDAO.createUser(user);

        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            userDAO.addRole(userDAO.getByEmail(user.getEmail()), role);
}
```

Я думал как-то вставить в даошки левый connection с autoComit = false, и работать с ним, но судя по документации, springJdbc в этом случае поступает как-то иначе.. Подскажите как правильно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Spring управление транзакциями вынесено в отдельный модуль [spring-tx](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-data-access).

Обычно используются декларативные транзакции, которые объявляются на уровне сервисов. В этом случае, вам нужно подключить [transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) и пометить метод или весь класс вашего сервиса аннотацией `@Transactional`, остальное Spring сделает сам.

Программное управление транзакцией также возможно, но [делается несколько сложнее](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic).

На самом деле в сети есть тонна гайдов по данному вопросу, чтобы сочинять еще один. Можете, например, обратить внимание на [этот](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-declarative-transactions-annotation.jsp).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Все получилось!